# Looping in R over variable in dataframe to get connected indexed variable

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing

I want to write a loop to index the dataframe to choose a value based on input of A.
I have a dataframe:

```
 A        B
1234    2017-01-01
1235    2017-01-02
1256    2017-02-03
```

My Code:

```
fun <- function(input) {
    for ( i in dataframe$A)
      if (i == input) 
      print(dataframe$B[A])

fun(1234)
> 2017-01-01
```

So, I what I want is when my input is A, how do I get B returned (that is connected to A) ?

Comment: And what's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, it's usually not necessary to use `for` loops. There are more elegant functions built into the language to help you subset data. This will give you the result you want.

```
dataframe$B[dataframe$A == input]
```

And if you want to use it as a function, you can do this.

```
fun <- function(input)
{
    dataframe$B[dataframe$A == input]
}
```